# Android:Fragment No View for ID for fragment

Tags: android-fragments, android-actionbar

I am trying to implement action bar tabs and during which i am facing an error in implementing the fragment class.

```
public class fragmentImplement extends Fragment 
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //setContentView(R.layout.fragment_layout);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout, container, false);
    }
}
```

And XML file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:text="Fragment A"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

kindly help as i am getting very depressed

Comment: Please post the stacktrace of the error.

Answer (score 0):

Please provide some more information (which error and where etc.) next time.

To use a `Fragment`s you also need a `FragmentActivity`. A `Fragment` is a reusable component which you can use in a `FragmentActivity`.

Please use this [tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/creating.html) as a starting point for using `Fragment`s then go one step further and take a look into [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Tabs) article.

As far as I remember there is also an example in the Android SDK which has an `ActionBar` with tabs.